# android get two jsonArray and inflate them

Tags: android, json

I have two json array (cast,crew) and I am using this code to inflate first one to my HorizontalScrollView.

```
    JSONArray casts = castImageResponse.getJSONArray("cast");

String image = null;
String name = null;

if (casts.length() > 0) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= casts.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject cast = casts.getJSONObject(i);
        image = cast.getString("profile_path");
        name = cast.getString("name");
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.index_actors_gallery,mGallery, false);
        ImageView img = view.findViewById(R.id.id_index_actors_image);
        Picasso.get().load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/h632"+image).into(img);
        TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.id_index_actors_name);
        txt.setText(name);
        mGallery.addView(view);


    }

}
```

When I am using this code for the second one, it's not working and only the first one works.
I think I need the second method start "only" after the first one finish.
How do I execute second one only after first one finish?

Comment: post your JSON response as well

Comment: Are you sure that the second JSON has the same structure as the first?

Comment: You don't need to wait until the first file is parsed, the loop does it for you. May be Picasso is running in the backgroud but I don't think so. I agree with @V.March, you're second JSON has perharps a different structure. Post your JSON arrays please.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the second JSON has the same structure as the first. This code works when i call them alone, but when I call them both only the first one works. this is my jsonArray pic: [link](https://pasteboard.co/I3y3kwB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I just put the theme in a separate try/cache, and works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting with an if condition

```
JSONArray casts = castImageResponse.getJSONArray("cast");
String image = null;
String name = null;

if (casts.length() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= casts.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject cast = casts.getJSONObject(i);
    image = cast.getString("profile_path");
    name = cast.getString("name");
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.index_actors_gallery,mGallery, false);
    ImageView img = view.findViewById(R.id.id_index_actors_image);
    Picasso.get().load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/h632"+image).into(img);
    TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.id_index_actors_name);
    txt.setText(name);
    mGallery.addView(view);
    if(i==casts.length()){ //for starting only after the first one finishes
        JSONArray crews = castImageResponse.getJSONArray("crew");
        String image = null;
        String name = null;
        if (crews.length() > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= crews.length(); j++) {

                        //code for cast repeated in crews
                        JSONObject crews = casts.getJSONObject(i);
                        image = crews.getString("profile_path");
                        name = crews.getString("name");
                        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.index_actors_gallery,mGallery, false);
                        ImageView img = view.findViewById(R.id.id_index_actors_image);
                        Picasso.get().load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/h632"+image).into(img);
                        TextView txt = view.findViewById(R.id.id_index_actors_name);
                        txt.setText(name);
                        mGallery.addView(view);

            }

        }

    }


    }

}
```